# Is there a way to compose an anonymous type object from JSON without knowing about the object's structure before-hand?

Tags: c#, json, .net-3.5

I have a JSON string and I'd like to use to compose an object. I don't know about the object structure or properties yet, so I cannot code a structure using an anonymous type. I'm stuck in .NET 3.5 on this project, so I don't have access to the new .Net 4.0 features yet. My goal is to use the converted object in a template engine similar to WebForms, Spark, or Razor to populate template items in a document with values from a model.

I have tried JavaScriptSerializer, which has a DeserializeObject method, but it outputs a key/value dictionary instead of an object that resembles the JSON object. Any other ideas?

If it helps, here's a unit test that expresses what I'm trying to do:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class when_deserializing_json_to_an_object : given_a_json_serializer_context
    {
        private object _expectedSerializedObject;
        private string _jsonStringToDeserialize;
        private object _result;

        protected override void Context()
        {
            base.Context();

            _expectedSerializedObject = new
                                            {
                                                Test = "123"
                                            };

            _jsonStringToDeserialize = "{\"Test\":\"123\"}";
        }

        protected override void BecauseOf()
        {
            _result = ObjectConverter.Deserialize(_jsonStringToDeserialize);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void it_should_return_the_expected_object()
        {
            var modelType = _result.GetType();
            var modelProperties = modelType.GetProperties();
            var testProperty = modelProperties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Test");

            testProperty.GetValue( _result, null ).ShouldEqual( "123" );            
        }
    }

public abstract class given_a_json_serializer_context : SpecificationBase
    {
        protected IObjectConverter ObjectConverter;
        private JavaScriptSerializer _javascriptSerializer;

        protected override void Context()
        {
            _javascriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            ObjectConverter = new JsonObjectConverter(_javascriptSerializer) as IObjectConverter;
        }
    }
```

(SpecificationBase is a class that our team uses to help us with BDD style specifications in MSTest)

So far, the production code born out of the specification above is as follows:

```
public class JsonObjectConverter : IObjectConverter
{
    private readonly JavaScriptSerializer _javascriptSerializer;

    public JsonObjectConverter(JavaScriptSerializer javascriptSerializer)
    {
        _javascriptSerializer = javascriptSerializer;
    }

    public object Deserialize(string json)
    {
        return _javascriptSerializer.DeserializeObject(json);
    }
}
```

At this point, it's clear that the JavaScriptSerializer isn't going to do the trick, because it just turns the JSON into a key/value pair dictionary.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this is going to work. Is your templating engine using reflection to access the deserialized object's fields? Is this a template engine you're writing or something else?

Comment: Yes, the template engine uses reflection to find all the properties. Then it iterates the properties and replaces the corresponding template items with the value of the property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't create an anonymous type like this but you can emit a new class.

Anonymous types are only anonymous to you.  The compiler generates an actual type for all anonymous types and at run-time there is a real type associated with the anonymous types.  Those types are not generated at run-time.

However, you can create a deserializer that uses `Reflection.Emit` or any similar (more powerful) library to generate a new class at run-time that has the appropriate structure and then instantiate and populate that class.

Answer (score -1):

You might find this of help Json.NET:

"Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET"

http://json.codeplex.com/